# Python download image on folder

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I have a problem with Python and Scrapy, i maked the script is still working and put all the data on MongoDB, but when he scraping he still take the photos only in database but i want to download in this structure /Project/photos/link-page/name.jpg

You have my code here!
This is Itmes.py

```
 import scrapy
from PIL import Image
class RedditItem(scrapy.Item):
    '''
    Defining the storage containers for the data we
    plan to scrape
    '''

    title = scrapy.Field()
    photoLink = scrapy.Field()
```

This is from setting.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = '/ProjectX/reddit/reddit/photos/'
```

Here i have the scrapper.py

```
    from scrapy.http import Request
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
    from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    from datetime import datetime as dt
    import scrapy
    from reddit.items import RedditItem
    from PIL import Image
def parse_following_urls(self, response):
        item = RedditItem()
        item['title'] = response.css('h1.kiwii-font-xlarge::text').extract_first()
        item['photoLink'] = response.css("div.kiwii-carousel-picture span::attr(src)").extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your images  like: `{IMAGES_STORE}/link-page/name.jpg`, you will need to extend the default ImagesPipeline class and override the method `file_path`.

For example:

```
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        # Code to generate {link-page/name.jpg} value
```

And then include it as a pipeline in your settings file instead of the default ImagePipeline:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'your_project.pipelines.ImagesPipeline': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! He dosen't give me any error but still not working.